# inputting a binary matrix via buttons

Tags: matrix, gui-construction, button

I want to input a binary matrix via buttons as in the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
initVariablesOut[] := Module[{r = Table[{k}, {k, 1, 4}]},
   If[Length[Flatten[row]] != 9, Print[REJECTED]; 
    row = {{}, {}, {}, {}}; Return[],];
   B = Array[0 &, {4, 9}];
   (B[[Sequence @@ #]] = -1) & /@ 
    Flatten[Outer[({#1, #2}) &, r[[#]], row[[#]]] & /@ Range[4], 2];
   Print[B // MatrixForm];
   ];
row = {{}, {}, {}, {}};
{TogglerBar[
   Dynamic[row[[1]]], {1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> "10", 
    6 -> "J", 7 -> "Q", 8 -> "K", 9 -> "A"}],
  TogglerBar[
   Dynamic[row[[2]]], {1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> "10", 
    6 -> "J", 7 -> "Q", 8 -> "K", 9 -> "A"}],
  TogglerBar[
   Dynamic[row[[3]]], {1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> "10", 
    6 -> "J", 7 -> "Q", 8 -> "K", 9 -> "A"}],
  TogglerBar[
   Dynamic[row[[4]]], {1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> "10", 
    6 -> "J", 7 -> "Q", 8 -> "K", 9 -> "A"}]} // MatrixForm
Button["run", initVariablesOut[], Method -> "Queued"]
```

The entries of B corresponding to the buttons which are pressed should have the value -1 and the rest should have the value 0. If not exactly 9 buttons are selected it should reset the buttons and do nothing except printing "REJECTED".

Question 1: I don't like my code, this must be possible way cleaner?!

Question 2: I'd like to delete all outputs every time I press run except my buttons (the run button and the buttons corresponding to the matrix). How would I do that? I found

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]]
```

but this deletes my buttons as well :(

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBH I didn't really read the question, but here's a way to make a custom object with a constructor GUI that I think follows what you want.

First we define a validator function to make sure the data is good and a constructor to get the data into the canonical format

```
ClearAll[BinaryMatrix, validateMatrix, constructMatrix];
validateMatrix[vals_List] :=
  Dimensions[vals] === {3, 3} &&
   Developer`PackedArrayQ[vals] &&
   Head[vals[[1, 1]]] == Integer;
constructMatrix[vals_List] :=
 If[Not@Developer`PackedArrayQ[vals], 
  {Developer`ToPackedArray[vals], True}, 
  {vals, False}
  ]
```

In this case I'm forcing a 3x3 packed array of integers (so not really binary). The second return value from `constructMatrix` simply tells us if the object needs to be rebuilt.

Next we define a constructor that sets the `Valid` flag and a nice format form

```
b : BinaryMatrix[vals_List]?System`Private`HoldNotValidQ :=
  
  Block[{data, rebuild, isValid},
   {data, rebuild} = constructMatrix[vals];
   If[rebuild, isValid = True, isValid = validateMatrix[data]];
   If[rebuild,
     BinaryMatrix[data],
     System`Private`HoldSetValid[b]
     ] /; isValid
   ];
Format[b_BinaryMatrix?System`Private`ValidQ] :=
  Interpretation[
   BinaryMatrix[MatrixForm[b[[1]]]],
   b
   ];
```

We can make one of these matrices like this, then

[image]

Note that the mis-shapen one doesn't format because it failed to validate.

Finally, we can make our constructor GUI. In this case I'll use `Checkbox` to make a table of 0 and 1. The key is that we provide a `BoxID` so we can replace the GUI using `BoxReferenceReplace` once we're done. I set this up to be very modular so that it can be easily adapted for other objects.

```
ClearAll[initializeMatrixInputGUIData, createMatrixInputGUI,
   constructMatrixFromGUIData, overwriteGUIWithMatrix];
initializeMatrixInputGUIData[] := ConstantArray[False, {3, 3}];
createMatrixInputGUI[Dynamic[data_]] :=
  Panel@Grid@
    Table[
     With[{i = i, j = j}, Checkbox[Dynamic[data[[i, j]]]]],
     {i, 3},
     {j, 3}
     ];
constructMatrixFromGUIData[data_] := BinaryMatrix[Boole@data]
overwriteGUIWithMatrix[mat_, id_] :=
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd@
  FrontEnd`BoxReferenceReplace[
   FE`BoxReference[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    {{id}},
    FE`SearchStart -> "StartFromBeginning"
    ],
   ToBoxes@mat
   ]
BinaryMatrix[] :=
 With[{id = CreateUUID[]},
  DynamicModule[
   {data = initializeMatrixInputGUIData[]},
   Column[{
     createMatrixInputGUI[Dynamic[data]],
     Button["Done", 
      overwriteGUIWithMatrix[constructMatrixFromGUIData[data], id]
      ]
     },
    Alignment -> Center
    ],
   BoxID -> id
   ]
  ]
```

This looks like
[image]

and after pressing `Done`

[image]

I have no idea if this solves your problem, but realistically it gives you the toolset you need to get the job done.

This is also easy to work into the `Dynamic[outputVar]` paradigm like

```
BinaryMatrix[Dynamic[var_]] :=
 With[{id = CreateUUID[]},
  DynamicModule[
   {data = initializeMatrixInputGUIData[]},
   Column[{
     createMatrixInputGUI[Dynamic[data]],
     Button["Done",
      var = constructMatrixFromGUIData[data];
      overwriteGUIWithMatrix[Defer[var], id]]
     },
    Alignment -> Center
    ],
   BoxID -> id]
  ]
```

where now `Done` will replace the object with the variable you specified for the output

Or if you want to allow for initializing the object/more advanced `Dynamic` controls

```
initializeMatrixInputGUIData[BinaryMatrix[v_]?System`Private`ValidQ] := 
  Map[(# === True || # != 0) &, v, {2}];
initializeMatrixInputGUIData[l_List] :=
  Replace[constructMatrix[l],
   {
    {a_List?validateMatrix, _} :> Map[
      If[Head[#] === Integer, # != 0, TrueQ[#]] &, a, {2}
      ],
    {a_List?(Dimensions[#] === {3, 3} && MatrixQ[#, BooleanQ] &), _} :> Map[
      If[Head[#] === Integer, # != 0, TrueQ[#]] &, a, {2}
      ],
    e_ :> initializeMatrixInputGUIData[]
    }
   ];
initializeMatrixInputGUIData[e_] := initializeMatrixInputGUIData[];
BinaryMatrix[Dynamic[var_]] :=
 With[{id = CreateUUID[]},
  DynamicModule[
   {},
   var = initializeMatrixInputGUIData[var];
   Column[{
     createMatrixInputGUI[Dynamic[var]],
     Button["Done",
      var = constructMatrixFromGUIData[var];
      overwriteGUIWithMatrix[Defer[var], id]]
     },
    Alignment -> Center
    ],
   BoxID -> id]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!